# how do I map my text box string into my url route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a text box that I enter data into and pass with a post to my 'home' controller on action 'results'

I want the url to end up looking like this when I post back

```
https://localhost:44301/Home/Results/San Francisco, CA, United States
```

I'm passing the text box data like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
                {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarautocomplete" name="location">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
                }
```

Here is my routing.

```
routes.MapRoute("SearchResults", 
            "home/results/{location}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Results", location = ""}
        );
```

How do I set my routing or my form to see the data that has been submitted as location in my url?

I can get it to look like this.

```
https://localhost:44301/home/results?location=San+Francisco%2C+CA%2C+United+States
```

but I want san francisco after /results/

Comment: When you post a form, it does not modify the url (it would need to be a GET) The value of the textbox will be in the `Request.Form` values

Comment: I can get it to show the user input in a get call like this home/Results?location=San..., but how do I get the location after a '/' like home/index/userinput?

Comment: You could do a POST to a method and then do a `RedirectToAction("Results", new { location = yourParameter });` but you would need to have the POST method have different parameters (say accept a model with a property named `location`) - but note that white space will be rendered as `San%20Francisco`

Comment: Is this your ONLY route? Please post your entire route config.

Comment: yes other then the default one that was there when I created the project, this is the only one.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to pass the value as a URL parameter? Why can't you just use POST data? It sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel a bit here.

Comment: Actually I have to pass a date as well, butthe date is optional. So I thought having the location in the url like I described would be good followed by the date as a parameter. ex. results/san-francisco-ca?date=02%12%2015. I'm trying to model it after www.airbnb.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StephenMuecke mentions in the comments, you could POST your search value to a (separate) action, then redirect to your results page, passing the location as a parameter:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarautocomplete" name="location">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string location)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Results", new { location = location });
}

public ActionResult Results(string location)
{
    return Content("location is: " + location);
}
```

You'll also to have the following route set up in your RouteConfig to get the friendly URL (make sure this is above the default route, as they match top-down).

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SearchResults",
    url: "Home/Results/{location}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Results" }
);
```

Comment: if I were to redirect, how would I add a date after the location? ex. san-francisco-ca-us?date=02/12/2015

Comment: You'll need to pass it as an additional parameter:  `RedirectToAction("Results", new { location = location, date = *DATEVALUE* });` Then update the signature of your `Results` action to accept a date.

Comment: Actually that would throw an exception. You cannot have GET and POST methods with the same signature.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Interesting, I tried this quickly in a sample project and didn't have any issues but may have missed something. Which signature are you referring to?

Comment: @rmorrin, Your have `public ActionResult Search(string location)` and `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Search(string location)` which will generate the following error: `Type 'HomeController' already defines a member called 'Results' with the same parameter types` (it wont compile)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but the actions definitely have different names: `Results` and `Search` (for the POST).